# times imported from excel worksheet to R incorrect

Tags: r, excel, date, time

I am trying to import a single large column of dates and times from excel worksheet ("System"). The column ("Registration_DateTime") is in a custom m/d/yyyy h:mm format, where both dates and times are in a single cell.  Here's an example from one cell: 4/26/2015 13:55.

When I import the date, the time somehow gets converted incorrectly. So, the 4/26/2015 13:55 cell is now "2015-04-26 06:55:00 PDT" in R.

I used read_excel to import the entire file. And I tried grabbing the column, `Registration_DateTime` after both with POSIXct and without. Using POSIXct, looks like this.

```r
Registration_DateTime <- as.POSIXct(System$Registration_DateTime, format="%m-%d-%y %H:%M").
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like your ingestion step presumes the source data is in UTC and that you want the imported data to be in your local PDT time zone, when in fact you want the time to be interpreted as local from the start. See suggestion here: https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/347#issuecomment-296495802

Comment: FYI, you assign to `Registration_DateTime` which is not saved within `System$Registration_DateTime`, is that intentional? What does `attr(System$Registration_DateTime, "tzone")` return? Have you tried `attr(System$Registration_DateTime, "tzone") <- "UTC"` to set it back to UTC?

Comment: doesn't ´format="%m-%d-%y %H:%M"´ need to match the custom "4/26/2015 13:55" pattern? so shouldnt it be "m/d/yyyy %H:%M"?

Comment: Thank you, @JonSpring. That seems to have done it!

Comment: @EirikFesker, see [`?strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) (perhaps unintuitive) for all of the `%`-codes used in identifying the format of a `POSIXt` or `Date` string. The single (non-`%`) strings `m`, `d`, and `yyyy` are all excel-centric, which works while _in Excel_ but not when processing the strings in R.

Comment: Hi @EirikFesker, I tried your suggestion and it did not work. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the timezone thing. R assume you are in PDT time zone, which is 7 hours behind Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). Therefore, "13:55" is shown as 13:55-7:00 = "06:55:00"

In your `as.POSIXct()` function, you can add another parameter `tz` for your correct timezone, for example `tz='UTC'`.